# How do I use a value as a key reference in jq?

Tags: jq

I have two JSON files as follows.

One contains a mapping of project to owners.

`owners.json`

```js
{
  "Project1": "owner1",
  "Project2": "owner2"
}
```

The second contains a list of projects with extra information:

`projects.json`

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Project1",
    "base": "A"
  },
  {
    "name": "Project2",
    "base": "B"
  }
]
```

I'd like to use JQ to merge the two files to look like the following:

`output.json`

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Project1",
    "owner": "owner1",
    "base": "A"
  },
  {
    "name": "Project2",
    "owner": "owner2",
    "base": "B"
  }
]
```

My first thought was to try something like this (assuming `projects.json` is fed on stdin):

```sh
jq --slurpFile owners owners.json '.name as $n | [.[] | {name, base, owner: $owners[0].$n}]'
```

This gives a syntax error relating to the `$n` in `$owners[0].$n`. What's the right way to do this in JQ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap variable references in square brackets for indexing objects with them. Even though you corrected that your script wouldn't work as arrays can't be indexed with strings (`.name as $n` part).

And don't bother with slurpfile, there are simpler ways.

```
$ jq 'input as $owners | map(.owner = $owners[.name])' projects.json owners.json
[
  {
    "name": "Project1",
    "base": "A",
    "owner": "owner1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Project2",
    "base": "B",
    "owner": "owner2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Out of curiosity, how would you do this if you could only supply `projects.json` on stdin instead of as a file? (I'm generating that data from a script. Consider the enclosing list `[ ]` in that file optional.)

Comment: @JohnS `... | $ jq '. as $owners | inputs | .owner = $owners[.name]' owners.json -` Like this.