# How do I merge these two different jsons using jq

Tags: json, merge, jq, appendchild, slurp

I have two simple jsons like:

info.json

```
[
  {
    "filename": "drilldown.json",
    "line": 14,
    "column": "43-49"
  },
  {
    "filename": "drilldown.json",
    "line": 10,
    "column": "38-44"
  }
]
```

keywords.json

```
[
  {
    "keyword": " `master1` "
  },
  {
    "keyword": " `Master2` "
  }
]
```

Would like to have the result as:

results.json

```
[
  {
    "filename": "drilldown.json",
    "line": 14,
    "column": "43-49",
    "keyword": " `master1` "
  },
  {
    "filename": "drilldown.json",
    "line": 10,
    "column": "38-44",
    "keyword": " `Master2` "
  }
]
```

In my case there's no relation between either of the json but would like them to be merged the way shown above

Any pointers regarding the same would be much appreciated. Thanks

Tried these two solutions were closest but they have some inter-relation between two json files

[Using `jq` to add key/value to a json file using another json file as a source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65762113/using-jq-to-add-key-value-to-a-json-file-using-another-json-file-as-a-source)

[How do I use a value as a key reference in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092531/how-do-i-use-a-value-as-a-key-reference-in-jq#new-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge (`add`) the items based on their index in their respective arrays using `--slurp` (or `-s`) and `transpose`:

```bash
jq -s 'transpose | map(add)' info.json keywords.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/lYCHxkDj0b9)

For a deep merge of two inputs, use `first * last` instead of `add`. For more than two inputs, use `reduce .[1:][] as $i (first; . * $i)` instead of it.

---

An iterative approach could skim through all the items using `to_entries` to access the indices, then add them successively using `+=`:

```bash
jq 'reduce (inputs | to_entries)[] as {$key, $value} (.; .[$key] += $value)' info.json keywords.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DfQxSHSTZy_X)

Again, use `*=` instead of `+=` for a deep merge.

---

You could also build up the entire result from scratch using `setpath` based on the `--stream` representation of the inputs:

```bash
jq --stream -n 'reduce (inputs | select(has(1))) as $i (.; setpath($i[0]; $i[1]))' info.json keywords.json
```

This approach always performs a deep merge.

---

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "filename": "drilldown.json",
    "line": 14,
    "column": "43-49",
    "keyword": " `master1` "
  },
  {
    "filename": "drilldown.json",
    "line": 10,
    "column": "38-44",
    "keyword": " `Master2` "
  }
]
```

Comment: Very precise and accurate. Super thanks @pmf!!!
This was exactly what I wanted
Sry my reputation is less than 15 and hence could not accept your reply as answer
But yours is the accepted answer